# After converting List to Set, enhanced for loop throws a ClassCastException

Tags: java, generics, rest

I have a problem after I convert `List<MyCustomObject>` to a `HashSet<MyCustomObject>`. When I try to iterate through each element using an enhanced `for` I get a `ClassCastException` stating that "java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to MyCustomObject".

Here is the code:

```
    List<MyCustomObject> myList = remoteMethod.getList();//the list is obtained via a REST call so it does go through the serialize/deserialize process...
    Set<MyCustomObject> mySet = new HashSet<MyCustomObject>(myList); 
    for(MyCustomObject object : mySet) <----this is where it goes boooom!!! 
        {
            DB.add(object);
        }
```

So before the enhanced for statement I extracted the first object in the list and used `.getClass` and it DID come up as `HashMap`. Is something happening during serialization/deserialization? Or is it in the conversion of the `List` to `Set`? What could be going wrong, and how would I fix it?

Comment: It might help to provide more information about what "the serialize/deserialize process" is, because that's probably where things are going wrong.

Comment: Just curious, is the REST query *supposed* to be returning `Map`s? It sounds like it might be returning a `Map` of key/value pairs that would potentially map 1:1 to properties on your `MyCustomObject`, but would need to be unmarshalled/bound onto it.

Comment: @Rob No it isn't it's supposed to be returning a list of MyCustomObject.. hmm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever is putting the data into the `List` that `remoteMethod.getList()` returns is putting `HashMap`s into it instead of `MyCustomObject`s. You should change it to put `MyCustomObject`s into the `List`.

The contents of the list are not *guaranteed* to be `MyCustomObject` instances [at runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), and that's probably what's creating your confusion.

Comment: @Rob The "remoteMethod.getList()" is actually a REST client call here is the code @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") public List<MyCustomObject> getObjects(final String authToken, final String locale) { return getRestTemplate().get( URI, authToken, locale, (Class<List<MyCustomObject>>) (Class<?>) List.class); } but the actual REST Method returns a List<MyCustomObject> which works perfectly...So I am guessing something is going wrong at the client..

Comment: The fact that you pass a `(Class<List<MyCustomObject>>) (Class<?>) List.class)` to `restTemplate.get()` for the type parameter is meaningless - RestTemplate only sees that you want a List, it can't know that you would like a List of MyCustomObject. Your own debugging shows that the RestTemplate is returning a List of Maps. Within your getObjects() code, you'll have to convert the response from restTemplate from a List of Maps to a List of your custom object.

Comment: In other words - at runtime a `(Class<List<MyCustomObject>>) (Class<?>) List.class)` is only seen as `List.class`, all the type information is erased.

Comment: @matt Is there anyway to specify the type of list I want in my client..I thought the cast would have taken care of that...but apparently it didn't :(. If there is no way then I will go ahead and delete it.  So I manually have to convert the list of maps to a list of MyCustomObjects by iterating through each..? Doesn't sound good at all...hmmm....

Comment: @Joe - You'd have to manually do it, regardless of whether or not you're casting. If the REST query returns an object that deserializes into a `List` of `Map`s, no amount of casting is going to magically turn that `List` of `Map`s into a `List` of `MyCustomObject`s; either the service needs to return `MyCustomObject`s, or you need to convert the data into `MyCustomObject`s yourself.

Comment: @Joe - Sure. It might not hurt to read up on [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), and perhaps also [inheritance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) (for a better understand of casting).